# InvoicePlane : List Payment Transaction on Invoice

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, invoice

I have installed [InvoicePlane](https://invoiceplane.com/) v1.4.6 on my Shared Hosting Account.
Able to perform regular tasks like, making Quotes and convert them to Invoice and almost all the functionalities which it was intended for.
Now, my Invoices require to display the transactions which has happened for this particular Invoice, for eg. Advance received, additional Advance Amount received.
We are registering each payment received with comments into the Payments section of the application.
Below is the steps I have taken and tried to see if I can get this option working.
Added a few codes of lines in the file `application/helpers/pdf_helper.php` as below:

```
$CI->load->model('quotes/mdl_quotes');
$quote = $CI->mdl_quotes->where('ip_quotes.invoice_id', $invoice_id)->get()->result();
$CI->load->model('payments/mdl_payments');
$payment = $CI->mdl_payments->where('ip_payments.invoice_id', $invoice_id)->get()->result();
$data = array(
    'invoice' => $invoice,
    'invoice_tax_rates' => $CI->mdl_invoice_tax_rates->where('invoice_id', $invoice_id)->get()->result(),
    'quote' => (isset($quote[0]) ? $quote[0] : null),
    'payment' => (isset($payment[0]) ? $payment[0] : null),
    'items' => $items,
    'payment_method' => $payment_method,
    'output_type' => 'pdf',
    'show_discounts' => $show_discounts,
);
```

I then added a few codes as table format into the Invoice PDF Template file `application/views/invoice_templates/pdf/InvoicePlane.php` as below:

```
<table class="item-table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Date of Payment</th>
            <th>Payment Method</th>
            <th>Amount Paid</th>
            <th>Payment Journal</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $payment->payment_date; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $payment->payment_method_name; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $payment->payment_amount; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $payment->payment_note; ?></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

So now, it came to a condition where the payment detail started to show up on the Invoice, but it is showing only the first transaction of payment received.
I guess I am missing some looping iteration to get all the line items of payment transactions of this particular Invoice.
I would request help and guidance to see how we can make it to display all the transactions of payment receipt for that particular Invoice.

PS : I did ask this on the InvoicePlane Forum as well, but no response that - https://community.invoiceplane.com/t/topic/2771.
I also did use their wiki - https://wiki.invoiceplane.com/en/1.0/templates/using-templates  and  https://wiki.invoiceplane.com/en/1.0/templates/customize-templates

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find the solution to this after trying many options.
Applied a `foreach` loop and got it to work.